# How to merge multiple images with size and position of specificity into a single image with text inscription (API)

Tags: php, laravel

I have three images, with the aim of making the first image a base while the two other images are placed on it. With the second image placed at the left corner (almost to the top) while the third image is placed nearly to the bottom of the right corner with a text inscription under it.

It is an API based application, I am writing to JSON (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload)

More also I have tried to use intervention image but I encountered a serious problem with the error as regards array expected instead of string and more also insert() is complaining of the column not found. That is why was I used raw PHP.

**The First Image** should cover the black background

[image]

**The second image** should be placed to the right (nearly top) corner

[image]

**The Third Image** is expected to be placed at the left bottom corner while the text will be wrapped under it.

my controller image is rendering the image scattered with the text above the image instead of under.

[image]

```
   public function upload(Request $request)
        {
            $x=$y=600;
                header('Content-Type: image/png');
                // $targetFolder = '/app/uploads/images/';
                // $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;

            $validation = $request->validate([
                        'title' => 'string',
                        'image' => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,webp|max:2048'
                    ]);

            $file      = $validation['image']; // get the validated file
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename  = 'mm-image-' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            $path      = $file->storeAs('/uploads/images', $filename);
            $image = storage_path('app/uploads/images/mm-image-1552822080.png');
            $c = storage_path('app/uploads/images/mm-image-1552936505.png');
            $im3 = file_get_contents($request->image);
            $outputImage = imagecreatetruecolor(600, 600);

            // set background to white
            $white = imagecolorallocate($outputImage, 255, 255, 255);
            imagefill($outputImage, 0, 0, $white);

                $first = imagecreatefrompng($image);
                $second = imagecreatefrompng($c);
                $third = imagecreatefromstring($im3);

                //imagecopyresized ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
                imagecopyresized($outputImage,$first,0,0,0,0, $x, $y,$x,$y);
                imagecopyresized($outputImage,$second,0,0,0,0, $x, $y,$x,$y);
                imagecopyresized($outputImage,$third,300,300,0,0, 100, 100, $x, $y);

                // Add the text
                //imagettftext ( resource $image , float $size , float $angle , int $x , int $y , int $color , string $fontfile , string $text )
                //$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
                $text = 'School Name Here';
                $font = storage_path('app/public/tahoma.ttf');
                imagettftext($outputImage, 16, 0, 300, 300, $white, $font, $text);

                $filename =storage_path('app/uploads/images/'.round(microtime(true)).'.png');
                imagepng($outputImage, $filename);

                imagedestroy($outputImage);
           }
```

**The expected Output** 
[image]

Comment: Well, you could use a `div` with a background image corresponding to the yellow one. Then inside the div you could arrange your inner images using flexbox.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention, it is an API. I am writing to JSON, already created an endpoint

Comment: you can do that with help of http://image.intervention.io/  make image with background insert other image's with size and position xy location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments by Gaurav Gupta, I suggest you to use Intervention Image PHP package which encapsulate all the GD methods into something easy to use (You can use Imagick also).

You could do something like this :

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{       
    $x=$y=600;
    $imageMerge = new ImageMerge();
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $validation = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'string',
        'image' => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,webp|max:2048'
    ]);
    $file      = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $hash      = Str::random(10);
    $filename  = 'mm-image-' . $hash . '.' . $extension;
    $path      = $file->storeAs('/uploads/images', $filename, ['disk' => 'public']);
    $image     = storage_path('app/uploads/images/mm-image-1552822080.png');
    $c         = storage_path('app/uploads/images/mm-image-1552936505.png');
    $im3       = file_get_contents($request->title);

    $logo = Image::make($file);
    $background = Image::make($image);
    $person = Image::make($c);

    // Resize the picture to insert to the good size
    $logo->resize(200, 320);
    $person->resize(300, 200);

    // Insert those pictures in the background to a specific position with some padding
    $background->insert($person, 'left', 30, 0);
    $background->insert($logo, 'right', 30, 0);

    // Draw white filled rectangle for the text
    $background->rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, function ($draw) {
        $draw->background('#FFFFFF');
    });

    // use callback to define details
    $background->text($im3, 0, 0, function($font) {
        $font->file(storage_path('app/public/tahoma.ttf'));
        $font->size(24);
        $font->color('#000000');
        $font->align('center');
    });

    // Resize image to specific output size
    $background->resize($x, $y);

    $exportName = 'file-'.$hash.'.'.$extension;
    Storage::disk('public')->put('/uploads/final/'.$exportName, $background);

    $imageMerge->image = $exportName;
    $imageMerge->save();
}
```

This is not a finished script. You still need to calculate all the exact position of elements and verify all the storage paths to be sure every file is imported correctly but in the end Intervention Image is really easy to use.

Here's the methods we used in the documentation so that you can tweak them to your needs :

- [Intervention Installation in Laravel](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)
- [Intervention Make method](http://image.intervention.io/api/make)
- [Intervention Insert method](http://image.intervention.io/api/insert)
- [Intervention Rectangle](http://image.intervention.io/api/rectangle)
- [Intervention Text method](http://image.intervention.io/api/text)
- [Intervention Resize method](http://image.intervention.io/api/resize)

Comment: I am also trying to save it to the specified location and also database

Comment: Check the code again, it was supposed to be $background

Comment: Ok, but the text is displaying likewise the background drawn in white rectangular . I have changed it to $background

Comment: You are saying that the text has the same color as the background ? To store the picture in the storage and database you have to make something like : `Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, $background);` and store the $filename in the database, you'll be able to retrieve it from http://yourwebsite.com/storage/mypicture.jpg if you symlinked the folder with `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: how to save to the database? I have saved to the directory using public_path('/uploads/images/file'.$i.'.png')

Comment: You don't save the picture in the database but just the name of the picture to be able to retrieve and create the url. Do you have a database ? Eloquent models ?

Comment: Yes I am able to do that but the entire path is inserted. Please, check the code I edited. The path name is $saveme and I made $imag->image = $saveme but this is all I have in it. How can I save the file name instead of the path /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/flavourvotes/Server/public/uploads/images/file3.png

Comment: I modified your edit to show how to use Storage facade and to save to your model only the picture name.

Comment: Sorry for the disturbance, the text size is not changing. I increased to 40 but so tiny that it is not readable even I increased to 100

Comment: I don't know maybe try another font or try something huge like 500.

Comment: This is error with the modified "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string"

Comment: Also in the text you use this `$im3 = file_get_contents($request->image);`. Shouldn't this be `$request->title` instead ?

Comment: Change it to `$extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();` instead.

Comment: It's weird that the previous line `$file` is working but the `$extension` one is not. You can try to retrieve the extension with the followin code as well `$extension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: I have rewritten the code but only challenged with reading from database.